# powershell winforms function output to textbox

Tags: winforms, powershell

I am looking for some assistance with a powershell GUI I am building.  I have a function that polls the bandwidth of a remote machine.  I am trying to figure out how to get it to output to a textbox.  What I currently get back just running this function by itself is below.  I would like just the value to display in the textbox

```
InstanceName                             value
------------                             -----
intel[r] i350 gigabit network connection 11.85
```

Also the last line in the function starts the loop process (Start-Monitoring) and runs every 10 seconds.  I have other functions in my powershell GUI and with the Start-Monitoring outside of the function brackets, it does not work correctly.  I am assuming that taking the Start-Monitoring at the bottom out and attaching it to a textbox would fix this

```
Function Start-Monitoring
{
    $Username = 'domain\user'
    $Password = 'password'
    $pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force

    $SecureString = $pass
    # Uses your password securely
    $MySecureCreds = New-Object -TypeName 
    System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username, $SecureString


        While ($true)
    {
                # Do things lots
                Invoke-command {Get-Counter -Counter "\Network Interface(intel[r] i350 gigabit network connection)\Bytes Received/sec" -sampleinterval 6 |select -exp countersamples|ft -a instancename,@{l="value";e={[math]::round($_.cookedvalue/.1MB,2)}}} -Credential $MySecureCreds -Verbose -ComputerName ipaddress

                # Add a pause so the loop doesn't run super fast and use lots of CPU 
                Start-Sleep 10
    }
}
Start-Monitoring
```

This is the textbox I built for it

```
#BandTextBox
#
$BandTextBox.Location = '175, 75'
$BandTextBox.Name = 'BandTextBox'
$BandTextBox.Size = '40, 20'
$BandTextBox.TabIndex = 4
$BandTextBox.Text = ''
#
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Save the out put in a variable and update the text box.

```
Function Start-Monitoring
{
    $Username = 'domain\user'
    $Password = 'password'
    $pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force

    $SecureString = $pass
    # Uses your password securely
    $MySecureCreds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username, $SecureString


    While ($true) {
            # Do things lots
            Invoke-command {Get-Counter -Counter "\Network Interface(intel[r] i350 gigabit network connection)\Bytes Received/sec" -sampleinterval 6 |select -exp countersamples|ft -a instancename,@{l="value";e={[math]::round($_.cookedvalue/.1MB,2)}}} -Credential $MySecureCreds -Verbose -ComputerName ipaddress

            # Add a pause so the loop doesn't run super fast and use lots of CPU 
            Start-Sleep 10
    }
}
$Output = Start-Monitoring


$BandTextBox.Location = '175, 75'
$Ban1dTextBox.Name = 'BandTextBox'
$BandTextBox.Size = '40, 20'
$BandTextBox.TabIndex = 4
$BandTextBox.Text = $Output.Value
```

Comment: With the $Output = Start-Monitoring, does this put it outside this specific function, like making it global?  I have several functions doing different things but written the same way.

Comment: `$Output = Start-Monitoring` is already outside the function, please execute and change the scoping accordingly.

Comment: With the above, my GUI does not open, what appears to be happening is that the loop is running as soon as I start my GUI but since it is not written as a background service, the form will never load.

Comment: Above reply is to get the output from the function and to set it to the text box, background processing has to be handled separately. you can try this function call as a Form load event activity.

Comment: Ok, so I think at this point, doing the event activity is beyond my knowledge.  Maybe for now. the better way for me to get this working, is to attach just the invoke-command to a button and display the result to a box, so the user is required to click every time for the result.  What is the best way to do that?  I already have other functions wrapped in other boxes that work, I have tried to copy these and just apply the bandwidth function, but the display does not show.